# How to Exit a FORM automatically?

Tags: vb.net

I created a VB project of the type Console App (.Net Framework). The objective of the below code is to make a FORM appear and then immediately disappear. However although the form is appearing correctly it is not closing by itself. Can anyone pls help pointing out my mistake? I tried to see how the control moves by setting up a break point and found that after executing the statement `Application.Run(New Form1)` (i.e. after launching the form) the control does not move to the next statement `Application.Exit()`  by itself. Only when I manually close the FORM (by clicking on x icon) do I find the control moving to the `Application.Exit()`  statement. But then I have already closed the form manually so does this statement at all do anything? If not, then how to modify the code to make the FORM automatically close after being visible.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form    'System.Windows.Forms.Form

End Class
Module Module1
    Sub Main() 'launches the console window

        Application.Run(New Form1) 'Opens a new Form
        Application.Exit()   'Supposed to close the form that was opened but not closing
    End Sub  'closes the console window
End Module
```

Also, please note I am deliberately not creating a WPF application as I want to understand how the classes/commands under the System.Windows.Forms namespace work.

Regards,
Sougata Ghosh

Comment: Application.Run does exactly what it was designed to do. It launches your form and keeps it open until you (or your users) close it. What will be the use of an application with an UI interface like WinForms or WPF that closes itself immediately after launch? And Application.Exit closes everything not just your form

Comment: Not clear why you have a Console app to test WinForms functionality. Anyway, you can declare a new Form instance, then Task.Run() `[Form].ShowDialog()` (so it will execute in a ThreadPool Thread, it won't block the Console app) and close it after, when needed. E.g., `Dim f As New Form() Task.Run(Sub() f.ShowDialog()) Thread.Sleep(3000) f.BeginInvoke(Sub() f.Close())`. `ShowDialog()` starts the Message Loop, so you don't need `Application.Start()`, it's *implicit*.

Comment: @Steve thanks for the clarification that a user needs to close the form. It wont close by itself at least in the code in which i have written. So thanks

Comment: @jimi ....thanks for the code piece. Actually

Comment: @Jimi The reason why I use Console App to test WinForms is because I wanted to understand how to use a certain functionality by writing codes. Had I used WPF and did a drag/drop then the code gets auto generated in the bckground which doesn't help a beginner like me to understand whats going on behind the scenes. Is there any other Project type where I can do this other than the console APP?

Comment: What is generated *in the background*, using either WPF or WinForms, are the default properties of Controls that are dropped on a Window/Form. There's nothing *hidden* anywhere (well, except what usually VB.Net hides from you, building a C# Project would be better for learnig). If you're learning about GUI Application, the build a GUI application. Using a Console app doesn't really add anything to the learning process. Maybe later, when you have better understanding of what is going on. Debug you app step by step to see what code is being called when the app is run.

Comment: @jimi ...thanks for the suggestion. Shall try doing it.